# Does DMARC help deliverability or is it simply a reporting mechanism?

Tags: email, dmarc

My client, has SPF and DKIM set up correctly but is having multiple failures when emailing certain organisations when emailing multiple people in the organisation. Recently we asked the Exchange administrator (who identified this as the issue) to whitelist our domain but obviously it's not always possible or identifiable in advance.

If I set up DMARC on the domain does it do anything else other than report on deliverability issues? And do I have to set it up through a third party (eg uriports.com)? or is it possible to set it up on our server?

Maybe I should say these are not bulk or unsolicited mail, they are generally transactional emails with multiple people (eg 3) in an organisation.

It was reported that this is a recent default setting on Office365 mail servers. Does anyone have any more information about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

DMARC is more than just reporting. If you are absolutely 100% sure that you have set up DKIM and SPF correctly, you can just add a DMARC record:

```
_dmarc.example.com    TXT "v=DMARC1; p=reject;"
```

You don't need to enable the report features, but you probably want to because the reports are very useful.

You can configure your own email address for aggregated reports, but these XML reports are not easy to read and understand. [URIports](https://URIports.com) gives you a lot more features for just $12 a year. They also have a one month free trial.

Learn more about aggregated DMARC reports here: https://www.uriports.com/blog/dmarc-aggregate-reports-explained/

While DMARC could increase deliverability, some major email providers have their own domain scoring technique for trusting email servers. A DMARC reject or quarantine policy certainly wouldn't hurt.